# Problems adding a VB dll to a C# project

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-3.5, reference

I am compiling and importing [this multicolumncombo box class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/multicolumncombo.aspx). I am able to run the demo program that comes with it without a hitch. However when I compile it for release and include the /obj/Release/CodeSamples.dll as a reference in my C# project, the examples won't work any more. Specifically, selecting an item doesn't work. I can add and display items properly, but when I click on an item, in the VB project it displays the first column's value, in the C# project, it doesn't display anything.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

once code is compiled into a dll it no longer matters if it was VB.net or C#. They all get compiled into IL. Chances are your problem is with your own code. Also don't add reference to the dll under the obj directory. Instead go for the one under the bin directory.

Comment: I am aware of this, and there shouldn't be any difference. My code is the exact same code the demo used, only I changed it to C#

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this specific control, but did you use a sample VB code snippet, porting it to C# in order to consume the control in your C# app?  I think VB arrays are 1-based whereas C# arrays are 0-based, so perhaps you have a 1-off problem in your C# code that accesses the control.

Just a guess.

Comment: they are, but that's not what I did. I compiled it, and added the dll as a reference in my C# application.